# ls -l vs ls -lL

Tags: files, permissions, ls, symlink

I know this looks like a duplicate, but previously asked questions do not answer my question

so in the shell I go to `/home` directory and create a directory there calling it `play`

then I go to this directory `/home/play`, and create two files, first one is a text file, second is a symbolic link to the terminal called `tty`

now if I use `ls -l` I get the following output
[image]

where as if I put `ls -lL` I get this [image]

what is this difference is supposed to mean? what do the question marks stand for?

Comment: "second is a symbolic link to the terminal" -- well that's a bit confusing way of putting it, since that's just a symlink to a file called `terminal`, not to a terminal or _the_ terminal in the usual sense of the word. A link to `/dev/tty` would be more like the latter.

Answer (score 33):

The `-L` option tells `ls` to show information for the target of the link, not the link itself. The red of `tty` usually indicates a broken link, or a link that points to a non-existent file, which is the case here. Since the destination doesn't exist, `ls` can't figure out the information to display, so it instead displays question marks.